# Mapping each transaction to its category as of that date

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to merge 2 dataframes in Python. I'm mapping based on 'ClinicCode'.

df1 contains 'visits' to a clinic, which belongs under a Panel, and the date of the visit.

Sometimes, Clinics might change panels, and this is recorded under df2.

Subquestion: Is the format of df2 the proper way to store values of such nature (i.e. its categorization might change over time)?

As such, Visit 1 to Clinic A during year 2019 needs to be tagged as under Panel A; whilst Visit 2 to the same Clinic A during 2020 needs to be tagged under Panel B; as Clinic A switched Panels (from A to B) at the start of 2020.

How should I go about doing this?

[DataFrame 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0cMDN.png)

[Dataframe 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/50XbP.png)

Comment: Hey Alex. Welcome to Stack Overflow. There are many posts dealing with the exact problem you have mentioned above. Check this link out: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=merging+datasets+%5Bpython%5D . Next time please try to search and see if there are any similar questions as yours.

Comment: Hi... did you try to understand my question? It is not a straightforward merge and I did try searching for a bit before I posted this question.

Comment: Alright then, I probably misunderstood the question. Could you please edit your question so it will contain an actual example of the desired output? Let me help you out :)